# How can we run performance testing manually for any webpage?

Tags: performance, testing

I am not able to find out anywhere that how can we do performance test manually.
Please help me out for this query.
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "manually" performance test a web page ? I think there are so many automated tools available that give precise and accurate results, so why would you prefer to do it manually?

Comment: I don't have any automation tool, that's why I would prefer manual test rather than automation.
Is there any provision to do it manually?
Thanks!

Comment: By definition, you cannot performance test an application manually. Manually == 1 user. Performance testing almost always involved > 1 user.

Comment: Hey Tom,
As per my knowledge, you are talking about load or stress test. Which requires more than one user to test.
But performance test is nothing just a time taken by a webpage to open.
Can you tell me is there any way to calculate that time response manually?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) or a similar tool.

Comment: Actually I don't have enough knowledge of these tools. Cant we run performance test without any tool?

Comment: @Sourabh JMeter is exceptionally well documented. Take an afternoon to get the basics down.

Answer (score 0):

What browser?  Most of the current browsers support the [W3C Navigation Timing spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/) and expose performance data directly on the DOM.  You can access it from the console, from javascript on your pages or from browser extensions that display the information.

If you want more detail like a resource load waterfall then you can usually access that directly from the dev tools provided by the various browsers.

One thing you will want to be really careful of is to make sure you do your testing in a configuration that is similar to the users.  If you are running a server locally and testing from a browser on the same machine or even the same network then your performance data will be pretty worthless (unless it's an intranet app).

Answer (score 0):

you can perform manual testing (Performance testing) for any webpage by optimizing your css, Javascript and images ( size).

I think JMeter is a best tool for same to check webpage testing if you want add some scripting you can also add.

Also you can check Yslow addons of firefox.This addons give you filter data to optimized your page perfromes. 
Also there are some online link available.

Answer (score 0):

> How can we run performance testing manually for any webpage?

You can simple use GTMatrix tool which will response of your site Performaces overall in detail.

Comment: An example of how to use this tool, or an explanation of how to implement it, would greatly improve your answer :)

Comment: Go to GTMatrix site https://gtmetrix.com/
Enter your Project link and click Analyze Button 
it will display all details E.g  what is your page load time ,

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go for Performance Testing without any tool is to provide a Standard loading time for each page as per one's experience knowledge. Else request the client to provide an ideal time for each page. Against which the loading time can be verified. But in case of multiple user simultaneously JMeter is the best hands on Approach available. Its Open source. Easy to understand. And you get reports too.

But of course there are multiple factors that would hinder the Performance. They are :

1. Your network speed
2. The Server speed on which your application is hosted
3. The number of Simultaneous users using
4. The Heavy images in pages
5. Last but not the least unnecessary links, codes, in short memory consumption in Code, could be loops not required. All the gifts from Developer Teams !!